# How can I make sure a threadpool is finished?

Tags: java, synchronization, threadpool, runnable

### The setup:

I am in the process of changing the way a program works under the hood. In the current version works like this:

```
public void threadWork( List<MyCallable> workQueue )
{
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(someConst);
    List<Future<myOutput>> returnValues = new ArrayList<Future<myOutput>>();
    List<myOutput> finishedStuff = new ArrayList<myOutput>();

    for( int i = 0; i < workQueue.size(); i++ )
    {
        returnValues.add( pool.submit( workQueue.get(i) ) );
    }

    while( !returnValues.isEmpty() )
    {
        try
        {
            // Future.get() waits for a value from the callable
            finishedStuff.add( returnValues.remove(0).get(0) );
        }
        catch(Throwable iknowthisisbaditisjustanexample){}
    }

    doLotsOfThings(finsihedStuff);
}
```

But the new system is going to use a private inner Runnable to call a synchronized method that writes the data into a global variable. My basic setup is:

```
public void threadReports( List<String> workQueue )
{
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(someConst); 
    List<MyRunnable> runnables = new ArrayList<MyRunnable>()

    for ( int i = 0; i < modules.size(); i++ )
    {
        runnables.add( new MyRunnable( workQueue.get(i) );
        pool.submit(threads.get(i));
    }

    while( !runnables.isEmpty() )
    {
        try 
        {
            runnables.remove(0).wait(); // I realized that this wouldn't work
        } 
        catch(Throwable iknowthisisbaditisjustanexample){}
    }
    doLotsOfThings(finsihedStuff); // finishedStuff is the global the Runnables write to
}
```

If you read my comment in the try of the second piece  of code you will notice that I don't know how to use wait(). I had thought it was basically like thread.join() but after reading the documentation I see it is not.

**I'm okay with changing some structure as needed, but the basic system of taking work, using runnables, having the runnables write to a global variable, and using a threadpool are requirements.**

---

### The Question

How can I wait for the threadpool to be completely finished before I doLotsOfThings()?

Comment: If there are any silly syntax errors, don't worry too much. This is simply a mockup of my actual code. I'll clarify any ambiguity though.

Comment: why the change to use a global variable to hold results? That might result in contention and create a bottleneck in your design.

Comment: @maasg, My application worked fine with one thread but started running out of memory when I was using callables, I had thought this was due to the callables not being garbage collected, thereby doubling the memory to store their results when I combined them into a single report. It turns out that I had been testing the production version in the past and my Ant script set different heap sizes for the IDE internal build vs. the production version. The IDE heap was 1/4 the size. I'll likely be converting it back to the first form now.

Comment: The 1st version is indeed better than the 2nd, but you are replicating some of the work of the ExecutorService with your submission/collection method. Have a look at my answer wrt use of `invokeAll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call [ExecutorService.shutdown()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29) and then [ExecutorService.awaitTermination](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29).

```
...
pool.shutdown();
if (pool.awaitTermination(<long>,<TimeUnit>)) {
    // finished before timeout
    doLotsOfThings(finsihedStuff);
} else {
    // Timeout occured.
}
```

Comment: Using shutdown on an executorService to get results is a bad practice.  It should only be used to finalize its lifecycle. Given the particular context of the original question (ie. this method being used like a 'main') it does answer the question, but is not good general advice. So, a downvote to lower the value of this answer as a general reference for others. Note that I answered the question after is was marked as 'answered', so it was certainly not for votes but to provide additional info to future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
pool.shutdown();
pool.awaitTermination(WHATEVER_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void threadReports( List<String> workQueue )
{
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(someConst); 
    Set<Future<?>> futures = new HashSet<Future<?>>();

    for ( int i = 0; i < modules.size(); i++ )
    {
        futures.add(pool.submit(threads.get(i)));
    }

    while( !futures.isEmpty() )
    {
        Set<Future<?>> removed = new Set<Future<?>>();
        for(Future<?> f : futures) {
            f.get(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            if(f.isDone()) removed.add(f);
        }
        for(Future<?> f : removed) futures.remove(f);
    }
    doLotsOfThings(finsihedStuff); // finishedStuff is the global the Runnables write to
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you weren't misled by my odd naming convention? threads isn't really a list of Threads, it's a list of Runnables. I seem to vaguely recall that it's possible to make a runnable run a thread though.

Comment: Like I said, this assumes you have access to the individual thread. Since you don't, I'll modify it for ExecutorService

Comment: @William I updated my snippet to loop around the futures (which you were ignoring before). What it does is store the future for each submission. Then it loops through until it's empty. Each iteration it looks at each active future and gives it 100 milliseconds to finish. If it is finished it flags for removal (which is done after the loop to avoid ConcurrentModificationException).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the [Fork/Join](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) framework that is now included in Java 7. If you do not want to use Java 7 yet you can get the jar for it [here](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/).

Answer (score 1):

`shutdown`is a lifecycle method of the `ExecutorService` and renders the executor  unusable after the call. Creating and destroying ThreadPools in a method is as bad as creating/destroying threads: it pretty much defeats the purpose of using threadpool, which is to reduce the overhead of thread creation by enabling transparent reuse.

If possible, you should maintain your ExecutorService lifecycle in sync with your application. - create when first needed, shutdown when your app is closing down.

To achieve your goal of executing a bunch of tasks and waiting for them, the `ExecutorService` provides the method `invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)`  (and the version with timeout if you want to wait a specific period of time.)

Using this method and some of the points mentioned above, the code in question becomes:

```
public void threadReports( List<String> workQueue ) {

    List<MyRunnable> runnables = new ArrayList<MyRunnable>(workQueue.size());
    for (String work:workQueue) {
        runnables.add(new MyRunnable(work));
    }
    // Executor is obtained from some applicationContext that takes care of lifecycle mgnt
    // invokeAll(...) will block and return when all callables are executed 
    List<Future<MyRunnable>> results = applicationContext.getExecutor().invokeAll(runnables); 

    // I wouldn't use a global variable unless you have a VERY GOOD reason for that.  
    // b/c all the threads of the pool doing work will be contending for the lock on that variable.
    // doLotsOfThings(finishedStuff);  

    // Note that the List of Futures holds the individual results of each execution. 
    // That said, the preferred way to harvest your results would be:
    doLotsOfThings(results);
}
```

PS: Not sure why `threadReports` is `void`. It could/should return the calculation of `doLotsOfThings` to achieve a more functional design.

Comment: Right now threadReports() void since it is somewhat like a main(). I am going to break it into smaller pieces as I get my algorithm smoothed out. I use the bad--but effective for me--development system of writing the initial program as about half OOP and half procedural. I do this instead of sudo-coding then convert it to a better structure once I'm happy with the processes under the hood.

Comment: And why did you -1 my post only?